# Retrieving matched items from an .Any() query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

So I have the following code:

```
var itemsGrouped = this.Errors.GroupBy(x => x.UniqueName).AsEnumerable();
var hasErrors = !itemsGrouped.Any((f) =>
{
    var errorCount = f.ToArray()
    .Where(x => x.ErrorCount.HasValue)
    .Count(x => x.ErrorCount.Value > 0);

    return errorCount > 2;
});
```

and now I want to retrieve the individual items that matched the .Any() query. How do I get only matching items?

Comment: What about using Where insted of any

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly, using the `Any()` function (it just returns a `bool`), but the `.Where()` function will return a filtered `IEnumerable<T>` which also has the `Any()` function.

So something like:

```
var itemsGrouped = this.Errors.GroupBy(x => x.UniqueName).AsEnumerable();
var invalidItems = itemsGrouped.Where((f) =>
{
    var errorCount = f.ToArray()
    .Where(x => x.ErrorCount.HasValue)
    .Count(x => x.ErrorCount.Value > 0);

    return errorCount > 2;
});

var hasErrors = !invalidItems.Any();

//Do stuff with invalidItems
```